# DB Schema - Job, Quote, JobStatus

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm designing a database (in MS Access 2010, but I think for this question this doesn't matter) to store information about quotes and orders for a joinery business.

This is my first big database project, and while I feel I have grasped the concepts of normalisation, I'm having some real trouble getting my head around quite how to structure the quote and job handling part.

Key points:

- When a customer makes an enquiry, a quotation or several quotations are produced.
- The quotations produced may include variations of the same thing. For example one quote may be for 10 windows painted in white, and another quote may be for the same windows painted in green (we charge extra for non-white colours). There may also be separate quotes eg. one for the windows on a house and one for some doors.
- This is for a joinery business, making bespoke windows, doors etc. - this means that quotations are produced but they do not refer to a "products" table since everything is a one-off. The person constructing the quote will simply write something like "Double window 1200x1000 - Bedroom 1" and a price in a separate field, and this line will be added to the quote.
- Each quote will have a set of details attached to it which are counted as overriding details for the whole quote. There are about 120 fields, some of which are for text and some of which are boolean which store information about the job. These are things like "Frame glass type" (text) and "Job includes sliding doors" (boolean). These are important as these fields keep a record of exactly what's been quoted and our designers will refer to them later on. They will also form the basis of an approval document which we send to the customer to sign off before we manufacture anything. I think this should be set up this way because it tends to be the case that if we are making say 10 windows for quote, they share pretty much all of the details like paint colour and glass type. There will also be a section/memo field for special notes about things which deviate from our standard specification etc.
- Quotes can have a status of "Live", "Dead", or "Progressed to order".
- One or several quotes can progress into a single "job" to be processed together and manufactured in one go. For example we might quote some windows and some doors separately, the customer decides they want to order both from us at the same time, so we process them together. Similarly a customer may have several "phases" to the same order, eg. they may have 10 windows from us one month, and 10 windows from us 3 months later when another part of their house is ready, even though they may have been quoted at the same time.
- Quotes will often need to be revised as customers change their minds about what they want.
- I also want each "Job" (which may consist of several quotes) to have a set of JobDetails which is a summarised list for the whole order.

Here's what I currently have: 
[image: Database relationship diagram]

But I'm really not sure if I'm going about it the best way as I have no experience with this kind of thing.

The Job table also links to an Accounts table which holds customers etc. but I haven't shown that as it's not wholly relevant to the problem at hand.

I'm thinking that "revised" quotes should actually create a new record, copying data from another quote and changing it, so as to create an audit trail, and the same with JobDetails - if the JobDetails on a job change and/or are different from a Quote's JobDetails then that needs to be flagged up (as the customer may need to pay more).

Does anybody have any recommendations of the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The following would be a much cleaner design - you've too many linked tables that don't need to be linked if the relationships are set correctly:

[image: EER]

I've left out the Payment tables in your example, they should be included as you have them above, the relationships are correct on those.

Also the JobDetails table can be merged with the actual job table as from your description above they have a one to one relationship - you can if you like still have it in a separate table, it would then just need to reference the job table only and not the quote tables etc

Comment: I probably should have made it clearer - I want to have an audit trail for the JobDetails. If the job has been quoted for as being painted White and one of the designers has changed it to being painted Green then I need this to be flagged up in the reports at the time of billing the customer (they will need to pay more!). Also the JobDetails need to apply to both jobs and quotes.

Comment: regarding job details: "I also want each "Job" (which may consist of several quotes) to have a set of JobDetails which is a summarised list for the whole order". You should summarise the details in your reporting software/procedure rather than in another table - ie using a Select statement.

Comment: also in terms of the audit trail, you should still be able to handle this in the QuoteLine table using different statuses, you could then use a superceded_QuoteLineID to link to the QuoteLine with the updated details - these will all be linked back to the job anyway through the relevant JobID - in terms then of following the audit trail that will be up to how you report on it.